# Select Same Column From 2 Tables into 1 Column in View

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, view

I have two column with the same name in different tables. 
I want to join them into one column in a view.

Here my first table `stocks`:

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
| stock_id | stock_cost | stock_left | item_id | purchasedtl_id | trx_id |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
|        1 |       1000 |          0 |       1 |              1 |      1 |
|        2 |       1000 |          5 |       1 |              2 |      2 |
|        3 |       1000 |          1 |       1 |              3 |      4 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+----------------+--------+
```

Second table `stocks_out`

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+------------+--------+
| stockout_id | stockout_price | stockout_qty | item_id | stock_id | saledtl_id | trx_id |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+------------+--------+
|           1 |           2000 |            1 |       1 |        1 |          1 |      3 |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+------------+--------+
```

And I want to join them to be like this `trx_id, trx_no, trx_closetime, trx_type stock_id, stock_cost, stockout_id, stock_out_cost, stockout_price, item_id`

`item_id` is the field I want to join in one column.

The current Query is :

```
select `transactions`.`trx_id` AS `trx_id`,`transactions`.`trx_no` AS `trx_no`,`transactions`.`trx_closetime` AS `trx_closetime`,`transactions`.`trx_type` AS `trx_type`,`stocks`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`stocks`.`stock_cost` AS `stock_cost`,`stock_out`.`stockout_id` AS `stockout_id`,`stock_out`.`stockout_price` AS `stockout_price` from ((`transactions` left join `stocks` on(`stocks`.`trx_id` = `transactions`.`trx_id`)) left join `stock_out` on(`stock_out`.`trx_id` = `transactions`.`trx_id`)) order by `transactions`.`trx_closetime`;
```

And the current result:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+
| trx_id | trx_no              | trx_closetime       | trx_type | stock_id | stock_cost | stockout_id | stockout_price |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+
|      1 | 02002-02-170415-001 | 2017-04-15 19:40:03 | 2        |        1 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |
|      2 | 02002-02-170415-002 | 2017-04-15 19:40:13 | 2        |        2 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |
|      3 | 02002-01-170415-001 | 2017-04-15 19:40:57 | 1        |     NULL |       NULL |           1 |           2000 |
|      4 | 02002-02-170415-003 | 2017-04-15 19:41:14 | 2        |        3 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Your sample data and query have nothing in common.  You should phrase this so the description, data, and query match.  For instance, there is no `item_id` in your sample result set.

Comment: I found the answer. Thanks anyway @GordonLinoff ! Actually I forgot to explain one transaction can't be in 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it guys. 
I just need to add the following query as the column

```
COALESCE(`stocks`.`item_id`, `stocks_out`.`item_id`) AS `item_id`
```

So the query will be like

```
select `transactions`.`trx_id` AS `trx_id`,`transactions`.`trx_no` AS `trx_no`,`transactions`.`trx_closetime` AS `trx_closetime`,`transactions`.`trx_type` AS `trx_type`,`stocks`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`stocks`.`stock_cost` AS `stock_cost`,`stock_out`.`stockout_id` AS `stockout_id`,`stock_out`.`stockout_price` AS `stockout_price`, COALESCE(`stocks`.`item_id`, `stocks_out`.`item_id`) AS `item_id from ((`transactions` left join `stocks` on(`stocks`.`trx_id` = `transactions`.`trx_id`)) left join `stock_out` on(`stock_out`.`trx_id` = `transactions`.`trx_id`)) order by `transactions`.`trx_closetime`;
```

And the result:

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
| trx_id | trx_no              | trx_closetime       | trx_type | stock_id | stock_cost | stockout_id | stockout_price | item_id |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
|      1 | 02002-02-170415-001 | 2017-04-15 19:40:03 | 2        |        1 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |       1 |
|      2 | 02002-02-170415-002 | 2017-04-15 19:40:13 | 2        |        2 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |       1 |
|      3 | 02002-01-170415-001 | 2017-04-15 19:40:57 | 1        |     NULL |       NULL |           1 |           2000 |       1 |
|      4 | 02002-02-170415-003 | 2017-04-15 19:41:14 | 2        |        3 |       1000 |        NULL |           NULL |       1 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------+----------------+---------+
```